# asp.net core identity login not working when run website with dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

when i'm running application with IIS Express Identity login work fine but when i'm running with .net core application.dll file login not working.

```
var result =
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.Remember, false);
is successful but :

bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

always returning false.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {      
        var result =
            await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.Remember, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user =await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

            UserProfile.UserId = user.Id;

              await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashbaord");
        }

        TempData["Message"] = "Error";
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Comment: this is my web.config file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Application.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 197a8bab-587a-4322-b587-87ff75864c49-->

Comment: Please check the order of app.UseAuthentication() in startup.cs. Try moving it before resolving functions and see if that make the difference

Comment: i check the order its already before resolving functions

Comment: Sounds good. If you can add your startup.cs config to the SO then it will helpful for additional debug.

Comment: thanks for your help but i figure out .
I enforce HTTPS on my application then my application worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

I enforce HTTPS on my application then my application worked fine!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio